# How to select multiple event date in MaterialCalenderView

Tags: android, calendarview

I am using [MaterialCalendarView](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) library, I want to select events dates problematically (no to be select by user in run time) which will  be multiple, After reading the documentation i saw four cases.

1. SELECTION_MODE_NONE
2. SELECTION_MODE_SINGLE
3. SELECTION_MODE_RANGE
4. SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE

I used SELECTION_MODE_NONE as i don't want user to select date.
I tried this but it doesn't show  me selected days which i passed.

```
private MaterialCalendarView materialCalendarView;
materialCalendarView = view.findViewById(R.id.newCal);
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 1);
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 7);
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 8);
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 9);
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 10);


    materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new CurrentDayDecatator(getActivity()));
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar, true);
    materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_NONE);
```

How to implement that? where i am going wrong?

**UPDATE**:
After taking the login of Umar and Manny i updated my code like this:

```
materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_NONE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 14);

    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 15);

    Calendar calendar3 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 16);

    Calendar calendar4 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 12, 17);


    materialCalendarView.addDecorator(new CurrentDayDecatator(getActivity()));
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar, true);
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar2, true);
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar3, true);
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar4, true);
```

So, now i get only the last date selected which is calendar4. But still i am unable to select multiple dates. and by default materialCalendarView selects today's date.

Comment: .setSelectionMode() should be called before you start accessing the  material calendar view

Comment: @Manny265 Okay, after doing this i am able to set my date but it is selecting only date instead of multiple

Comment: materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode(MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE)

Comment: Yes tried this also, but in that case MULTIPLE will allow user to select dates. but when i give multiple dates it is not selecting

Comment: [this](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/issues/541) answer says i have to create a array of dates which i want to select but i don't know how exactly i can do it.

Comment: why not use calendarView.setEnabled(false) to stop the user from selecting. But still, selection mode has to be multiple. no need for array, depends where the Dates are coming from, you can choose to loop thru a data source

Comment: i did calendarView.setEnabled(false), but still user is able to click dates from calender. and in this case also it is taking only one date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after doing lots of tweaks and with the suggestions of Manny and Umar i finally found the way how to set multiple days in materialCalendarView. So this is how it done.

1. I dont want user to select dates from calendar, so added this line in my code:

   ```
   materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode (MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_NONE);
   ```
2. Now i want to set multiple dates, for this i am creating multiple calendar objects and padding dates in it like this...

   ```
   Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar.set(2017, 11, 14);

   Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
   calendar1.set(2017, 11, 16);
   ```
3. And finally it was selecting multiple dates, but it is also selecting today's date which is not a problem. but now when i pass month as 12(december) it is showin me next month 12+1 which means january of next year. So for this i am passing a value less than what i want.

Final Code:

```
materialCalendarView.setSelectionMode (MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_NONE);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2017, 11, 14);

    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar1.set(2017, 11, 16);

    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar, true);
    materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar1, true);
```

Thanks Manny and Umar :)

Answer (score 1):

you are setting date on same instance of Calender object. You need multiple calender object and then set those objects to the `materialCalenderView`

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(2017, 12, 1);

Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar2.set(2017, 12, 7);

materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar, true);
materialCalendarView.setDateSelected(calendar2, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I tried by giving 2 calendar objects but still no change. materialCalendarView is selecting todays date by default. By the way what MODE should i select? SELECTION_MODE_NONE or SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE

Comment: you should use SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE according to the docs. https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview/blob/master/docs/CUSTOMIZATION.md#date-selection

Comment: Okay, But adding dates into the calendar is challenge for me now.

Comment: but when i keep mode as SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE, user will be allowed to clicked calenderview and select dates which i dont want

Comment: you just want the user to view the dates ?

Comment: Yes. on click of those selected dates problematically, ill show toast or do something about that specific date event

Comment: it should work with the SELECTION_MODE_NONE  as well because you are setting date not the user. have you tried it ?

Comment: I tried that. user was not able to select date.. but the dates which i passed were not getting selected.

Comment: It is selecting only todays single date by default
oveeriding my provided date

Answer (score 0):

I was trying out this library and came through this problem. Seems like the library has been updated and the solution provided here doesn't work anymore.

Here is the updated code, it's in Kotlin;)

```
val calendarView = findViewById<MaterialCalendarView>(R.id.calendar_view)
    
    val day1 = CalendarDay.from(2023, 2, 15)
    val day2 = CalendarDay.from(2023, 2, 12)

    calendarView.selectionMode = MaterialCalendarView.SELECTION_MODE_MULTIPLE
    calendarView.setDateSelected(day1, true)
    calendarView.setDateSelected(day2, true)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.CalendarDay;
CalendarDay calendarDay = CalendarDay.from(data.getYear(), data.getMonth(), data.getDay());    
calenderDialogBinding.calender.setDateSelected(calendarDay,true);
```